# How to attach view button to an item list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Please I am currently displaying a list of business from a businesses array. Each business has its unique id. I am displaying the businesses by mapping my business array through a react "Business Card Component" This card is a small materialize card that shows few properties of the business.

The API endpoint to get the full details of a particular businesses is < url/businesses/id >
On each business card, I have a button which says "visit", such that when a user clicks the button, he send request to url/businesses/id, and when the request is successful, I will update the state using redux and render the BusinessProfile page that will render the business particulars.

My approach is to concatenate url/businesses/ with the id of business and send the request.
But I dont know how to access the business id  from the "visit" button.

```
 const FoundBusinesses = realBusiness.map((eachBusiness, index) => {
        return (
            <BusinessCard key={index}
                business={eachBusiness}
                businessPic={profilePicture}
                handleClick={this.handleClick}
            />
        )
    })
```

I will appreciate any help please

Comment: your question is how to pass `businessId` to `handleClick` function?

Comment: @IgorAlemasow, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'visit' button is inside BusinessCard, you should already have the id inside eachBusiness.businessId, correct? And if I am understanding your question correctly, you can pass it to your handleclick function and change the URL. The below code is using history from react-router to change the url.

### With an arrow function inside the button

HandleClick:

```
handleClick(businessId) {
  this.props.history.push(`url/businesses/${businessId}`)
}
```

Inside BusinessCard:

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(this.props.business.businessId)}>
  See business info
</button>
```

HandleClick will use that particular Id when it executes so it pushes to the correct URL.

### With a closure

You can also do the same with a closure for cleaner function call:

```
handleClick(businessId) {
  return () => this.props.history.push(`url/businesses/${businessId}`)
}
```

Inside BusinessCard:

```
<button onClick={this.props.handleClick(this.props.business.businessId)}>
  See business info
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you @Steve Banton

`...onClick={this.props.handleClick('businessId')}>`

   In the above code, I need to pass the businessId to handleClick.
 That is where the problem lies,
 I cannot do `this.props.business.id inside the argument`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why not?

Comment: If you follow the code example above and make sure to return a function before calling history.push (the closure) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleClick={() => {this.handleClick(business.id)}
```

This link is also good, it shows you how you can send your data as a parameter to your click handler. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reactjs-pass-parameters-to-event-handlers-ca1f5c422b9